# Unable to solve "ImportError: No module named '_tkinter'"

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

When I try to run my program I keep getting the `ImportError: No module named '_tkinter'` error. I tried two things which I found could solve this problem:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tk

sudo apt-get install tk-dev
```

They both say that they are up to date but I still get the `no module named '_tkinter'`.

Edit:

The error points to this line `from tkinter import *`

This is how I run the program that produces the error:

```
python3 myprog.py
```

Comment: Without knowing what statement caused the problem (full error message) we can only guess what is wrong, which is usually a waste of time.

Comment: @CurlyJoe Sorry I edited the question to include this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this code and see what it says

```
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    import Tkinter as tk     ## Python 2.x
    print("Python 2.X")
else:
    import tkinter as tk     ## Python 3.x
    print("Python 3.X")
print "version", tk.TclVersion
```

Comment: I put this code into a python file and included import tkinter as shown above. I got the same error again.ImportError: No module named '_tkinter' at the same line as before.

Comment: EDIT: I put this code into a python file and  I got the same error again.ImportError: No module named '_tkinter' at line 6 in your example above.

Comment: Either it was not installed correctly, or it is a permissions problem.  Time to go to the forums for whatever Linux distro you are using and do a search for installing tkinter for Python3 for a user.